# Why java allows TreeMap keys and TreeSet values to be non comparable?

Tags: java, treemap, treeset

Here's header of java TreeMap implementation(1.8_071):

```
public class TreeMap<K,V>
    extends AbstractMap<K,V>
    implements NavigableMap<K,V>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
```

Why there's no restriction, like this:

```
 public class TreeMap<K extends Comparable<?>,V>
        extends AbstractMap<K,V>
        implements NavigableMap<K,V>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
```

Answer (score 9):

Because, as the doc says, you can use a key that is not a Comparable and provide a Comparator object:

```
TreeMap(Comparator<? super K> comparator)
Constructs a new, empty tree map, ordered according to the given comparator.
```

(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

Answer (score 1):

TreeMap sorts based on natural ordering of keys as per documentation i.e. it uses compareTo methods defined on keys. If no compareTo is found, I guess it won't bother sorting unless you supply a comparator class while constructing TreeMap.

The benefit of this is you don't have to supply a custom comparator while constructing your TreeMap. TreeMap automatically sorts based on compareTo methods on key objects.